# async await execution windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, c#-5.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am new to async and await style of programming. How can I solve the following problem:

I am calling the below code first.  The problem here is that the first line is awaiting which need to populate the `categoriesvm.Categorieslist`, which it does not, but the second line is called. (which I think is the default behaviour of await)

How can I make sure that the second line is called only when the `categoriesvm.Categorieslist` is populated in the first line?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    categoriesvm.GetCategories();                 
    BookCategories.DataContext = from vm in categoriesvm.Categorieslist select vm;
}
```

In the code above when I execute the first line it goes below where `Categorieslist` is the list I am accessing above.

```
public async void GetCategories()
{            
    Categorieslist = new ObservableCollection<Categories>(await PhoneClient.GetDefaultCategories());          
}
```

The `phoneclient` is below

```
public class PhoneClient
{   
    private static readonly HttpClient client;

    public static Uri ServerBaseUri
    {
        get { return new Uri("http://169.254.80.80:30134/api/"); }
    }

    static PhoneClient()
    {        
       client =new HttpClient();
       client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
    }      

    public async static Task<List<Categories>> GetDefaultCategories()
    {      
        HttpResponseMessage getresponse = await client.GetAsync(ServerBaseUri + "Categoryss");                      
        string json = await getresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();         
        json = json.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);
        var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Categories>>(json);
        return categories.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid `async void`. I explain this guideline in an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Once you change your `async void` method to `async Task`:

```
public async Task GetCategoriesAsync()
{            
  Categorieslist = new ObservableCollection<Categories>(await PhoneClient.GetDefaultCategories());          
}
```

Then you can `await` it as such:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  await categoriesvm.GetCategoriesAsync();                 
  BookCategories.DataContext = from vm in categoriesvm.Categorieslist select vm;
}
```

However, I recommend doing all your VM initialization outside of your UI events - this will make your code easier to test. Take a look at my [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) blog post for ideas.