# Retrieving Location on page open

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a page and when it´s going opened, I want to retrieve the GeoLocation of the phone.
Here is my code:

```
public partial class splash : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        StatusTextBlock.Text = "Ermittle Position ...";
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;
        try
        {
            Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                );
            LatitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.000000");
            LongitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.000000");
            StatusTextBlock.Text = "Done.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80004004)
            {
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "GeoLocation im Device deaktiviert !";
            }
            else
            {
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "Sonstiger Fehler aufgetreten !";
            }
        }
        StatusTextBlock.Text = "Fertig ...";
    }
```

The problem seems to be the line `Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync`. I changed the declaration of `OnNavigateTo` to `async` shown here ([async await execution windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540570/async-await-execution-windows-phone-8)) but now my code seems to wait "endless" because `"Fertig ...`" is never written to my TextBox.

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the timeout?
Since it is the first time you are getting the current position it can take a little while longer...

Comment: If I add a button to the page and run the code within a Click event, the settings (timeout and accuracy and Age) are OK and all runs fine... but I want to run the code on page open.

Comment: And you declare the Geolocator within the Button Click Event?
Please try increasing the timeout and, as @Dream Coder said try to also increase the DesiredAccuracyInMeters. At least this way you will make sure if the problem is related with the GPS aquiring the position (not having time to) or if it is any other problem.

Comment: Yes in the Button click Event. And there it works with the Settings - but not within OnNavigatedTo. I Need an accuracy of 10-20 meters...

Comment: I tested the above code and I had no problem.
Can you debug it and see the output console?

Not getting the problem here :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Increase the DesiredAccuracyInMeters and try again. use 50 you would get desired results, the less the desired accuracy in meters the more time its gonna take.

if you really want the position to be accurate i.e, accuracy in 5 meters, in that case as @Andre said increase the time out. hope this helps.